# Cannot set location of an XCUIDevice to nil

Tags: xcode, location, uitest

My UI tests require that property `location` of a `CLLocationManager` instance is initially `nil`.
Thus, in the scheme for the UI tests, the run options set the default location to `none`.

The UI tests use

```
class IPhone_UITestCase: XCTestCase {
    //…
    let device = XCUIDevice.shared
    //…

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        device.location = nil
        //…
        myApp.launch()
        //…
    }
```

and the app uses a singleton

```
final class LocationManager: CLLocationManager {
    static let shared = LocationManager()
    //…
}
```

I expected that in my app after launch, `LocationManager.shared.location == nil`.

However, the app is launched with `location != nil`.

What could be the reason?

**EDIT:**

When the UI test is stopped at a breakpoint after setting the simulated device location to `nil`, one has the following situation:
The Xcode console shows for the UI test app `Resetting the simulated location`, as expected.
But for the app, the Xcode console shows that the `CLLocationManager` did call `locationManager(_:didFailWithError:)` in its delegate, with the error `The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)` and the simulated device location was **not** reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Apple (TSI) and got the answer

> … we believe your question is answered by the Xcode documentation
> linked here:
>   Construct locations for unit tests
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/simulating-location-in-tests#Construct-locations-for-unit-tests

The docu says:

> ... update the simulated device location by setting the shared
> XCUIDevice location to an instance of XCUILocation.

Apparently this has to be interpreted that it is not allowed (even if possible) to set the `location` property to `nil`, since nil is not an `XCUILocation`.